# What are common sizes for zones in the heroic tier?

Tags: dnd-4e

My wife wants to make some area markers for zones and such that powers create.  She has a bunch of burst 1 powers at the moment.   Before she starts making them she wants to know what other sizes she might be needing.

I've seen some burst 3 w/ minor sustain druid powers (or maybe "until end of encounter").

Is there a list of what sizes are common in heroic tier?   Or is there some non-insane way to use the compendium to research it?  (i.e. not "scrape all the info, post process the data...")

Comment: It's not nearly as cool visually, but my group just uses 4 coins to mark the corners of zones. Just an idea if you're in a pinch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To address your meta-question, you can search DDI for common sizes, like so:

- `zone` levels 1-10, returns 153 results
- `zone burst 1` levels 1-10,  66 results
- `zone "burst 2"` levels 1-10, 33 results
- `zone "burst 3"` levels 1-10, 16 results
- `zone "burst 4",` levels 1-10, 0 results
- `zone "burst 5",`, levels 1-10 12 results
- 0 results for 6..9
- `zone "burst 10"`, levels 1-10, 2 results

Of course, you can select out druid for even more precise queries.

Roughly speaking, a 3x3,5x5, and 7x7 should serve your purposes. While there and 11x11 and a few 21x21 they are effectively "entire battlefield" for most reasonable values of "battlefield"

These sizes are also useful for documenting monster auras. In my experience, a wire guide enamelled with a certain colour, is probably your best bet, as it doesn't involve replacing every figure on the board when a zone or aura changes. You can also use them for quickly estimating ranges and bursts for normal powers.